# usar un struct para leer de un fichero con fread

Tags: struct, archivo, fread

intento hacer una lectura con un struct, desde un fichero (binario.txt). donde hay una lista de letras con un codigo binario en 2 columnas

[image: este es el archivo]

la intencion es leer todos los datos en una sola lectura y guardarlos en sus variables correspondientes. pero al final me guarda todos los datos en la primera variable en array que creé en la funcion lectura. despues va quitando de 2 en 2 los datos para las siguientes variables.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
```

//defino mi struct

```
typedef struct LetrasBinarias{
    char let;
    int bin;
}letb;
```

//mis funciones

```
int LeerArchivo(int conti);
int Contador();
```

//mi main

```
int main(void){
    int cont;

    cont=Contador();
    LeerArchivo(cont);
}
```

//funcion para saber cuantos registros hay

```
int Contador(){

    char temp[10];
    int cont=0;
    FILE *pf;

    if((pf=fopen("binario.txt","r"))==NULL){
        printf("No se ha podido abrir archivo.\n");
    }
    else{
        while(!feof(pf)){

            fgets(temp,50,pf);
            cont++;
        }
        rewind(pf);
        printf("El contador es: %d",cont);
        fclose(pf);
    }
    return(cont);
}
```

//mi funcion para registrar los datos como texto y como  entero

```
int LeerArchivo(int conti){
//Variables
    letb a[conti];
    FILE *pf1;

    int i=0;

    if((pf1=fopen("binario.txt","r"))==NULL){
        printf("No se pudo leer el archivo.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nLEIDO DE ARCHIVO:\n");

        fread(&a,sizeof(letb),conti,pf1);

        for(i=0;i<=conti-1;i++){
                printf("El contador es i: %d\n",i);
                printf("El caracter es: %s\n", &a[i].let, &a[i].bin);
                printf("El binario es: %d\n", &a[i].bin);

        }

    }
    fclose(pf1);
}
```